# What Directory do I use

Tags: directory

So I'm looking for the Directory I can use for any computer

Since C:\Users\Cole\Documents\ would only work on my computer what should I replace it with I tried C:\Users\User\Documents\  but it didn't work

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? is this related to programming?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `C:\` or alternatively PowerShell has the `~` home directory.